# Why does one VB.net project properties list Configuration and Platform and another does not?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I just created a new VB Windows forms project using VS2010. The solution also contains a Fortran DLL project.  I've set the platform to x86.

When I pull up the VB project properties it does not list the configuration or the Platform at the top of the properties dialog.  This means I can't set the Compile tab Build output path differently for debug or release.

I've created several similar solutions using VS2008 and recently converted them to VS2010 and have not had this problem.

Mike

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're actually seeing?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are using VS2010 Express and your single project is not in a solution project.

You could manually change the output from your .VBPROJ file with notepad. Inside that file you  could do other changes . FOr exemple switching from Debug to Release. You have to restart your VS2010 Express edition to apply the changes (if I am not mistaken and it will be onkly true if you are using the Express Edition)